# How does ViewModel in Android Studio handle configuration change behind the scenes?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I have been playing around with viewModels, however what puzzles me is how `ViewModels` handle configuration changes behind the scenes, here is an example

**Viewmodel**

```
class InitiateviewModels: ViewModel() {
    var list:MutableLiveData<MutableList<Int>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun fillingList(){
        var Integerlist = mutableListOf<Int>(1,2,3,4,5)
        list.setValue(Integerlist)
    }
}
```

In the `ViewModel` class, I append the `list` property with a new `Integer` list whenever `fillingList()` method gets called.

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var Initiation:InitiateviewModels
    lateinit var text:TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Initiation = ViewModelProvider(this)[InitiateviewModels::class.java]
        text = findViewById(R.id.textView1)
        Initiation.fillingList()

        Initiation.list.observe(this, Observer{
            text.text = it.toString()
            Log.d("Answers", "${it?.size}")
            Log.d("Answers", "From Viewmodel ${Initiation.list.value?.size}")

        })
    }
}
```

In the `MainActivity`,we call the `Initiation.fillingList()`, to append the list of integers `Integerlist` to the `list` property in the `ViewModel`, we attach observers to the `list` property , we `Log` the size of the list and show the list on the `textview`

[Size of list after a configuration change, both from Observers and directly from the viewmodel property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWy6J.png)

[How the UI looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKwaN.png)

Each time the configuration changes, the `OnCreate` functions stops and gets restarted, meaning `OnCreate` gets called again, if `OnCreate` is called again, wouldn't it call `Initiation.fillingList()` again meaning each screen rotation would increase the `list` property `size` by 5?

So when first loading the app the size of the `list` property would be 5, then 10, 15,20,etc everytime the screen is rotated. What could possibly be the reason for the list not becoming bigger and bigger everytime the `Initiation.fillingList()` is called?

According to the docs `This caching means that you don’t have to fetch data again through common configuration changes, such as a screen rotation.`, how does this work in this case scenario?

I was just playing around, testing concepts out.

Comment: You are changing the list contained in the LiveData, you're not adding elements to the existing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code of yours more closely:

```
fun fillingList(){
    var Integerlist = mutableListOf<Int>(1,2,3,4,5)
    list.setValue(Integerlist)
}
```

You are not adding to or enlarging an existing list. You are *replacing* the LiveData's list with a new one each time this is called, so when you inspect the LiveData contents it is always the same size.

By the way, variables and property names should not start with a capital letter--that is very confusing to read because that kind of naming by convention would me you're accessing a static `object` rather than an instance of a class.

Comment: Oh yeah, `setValue` essentially sets a new value for the `list` variable not appending, Thanks for informing me about the naming conventions.